# Global function in app express.js

Tags: express

Trying to use a function in app, that can be called in actions.

Put in app.locals doesn't work :

```
app.locals({ 
    "form_tag" : helpers.form_tag,
    "text_field_tag":helpers.text_field_tag,
    sendHttpGs: function(req,res) {
        var querystring = require('querystring');
        var data = querystring.stringify({
            idSong: req.params.idSong
        });

        var data = querystring.stringify({
            track: req.body.track
        });
        var options = {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 8888,
            path: '/exo/playlists/searchIndex.php',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
            }
        };
        var reqSong = http.request(options, function(ret){
            ret.setEncoding('utf8');
            ret.on('data', function(chunk){
                req.session.search.push(JSON.stringify(chunk));
                res.render('search.ejs', {
                    tracks: chunk,
                    title: req.session.search
                });
            });
        });
        reqSong.write(data);
        reqSong.end();
    }
});
```

This part is for sending http post to a php file that gets login and search function.

Where should I put it in order to use it like

```
.post('/loggedin', function(req,res){
    global.sendHttpGS(req,res);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a function to the app object via app.set(), for example so something like this in your initialization code:

```
app.set('sayHello', function(res) {
  return "hello";
});
```

Then in your routes, the function will be available via req.app.settings:

```
req.app.settings.sayHello(res);
```